# Error Assertion `args[3]->IsInt32()' failed

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

- **Version**: v12.19.0
- **Platform**: Linux ayungavis 5.4.0-48-generic #52~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 12:50:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- **Subsystem**:

#### What steps will reproduce the bug?

I tried to follow the tutorial from [Adding a Database to GraphQL](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/4-adding-a-database/), this is the code of my `script.ts`:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client")

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

async function main() {
  const allLinks = await prisma.link.findMany()
  console.log(allLinks)
}

main()
  .catch(e => {
    throw e
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.disconnect()
  })
```

#### How often does it reproduce? Is there a required condition?

Everytime when I run it using `node src/script.ts` or `ts-node src/script.ts`.

The requirements:

- @prisma/cli
- @prisma/client

#### What is the expected behavior?

Show all links from the database using prisma client.

#### What do you see instead?

I tried to run the `script.ts` using `node src/script.ts` and `ts-node src/script.ts` but show the following error:

```
/usr/bin/node[20367]: ../src/node_http_parser_impl.h:529:static void node::{anonymous}::Parser::Initialize(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `args[3]->IsInt32()' failed.
 1: 0xa17c40 node::Abort() [/usr/bin/node]
 2: 0xa17cbe  [/usr/bin/node]
 3: 0xa3214a  [/usr/bin/node]
 4: 0xc019e9  [/usr/bin/node]
 5: 0xc037d7 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/bin/node]
 6: 0x1409319  [/usr/bin/node]
```

#### Additional information

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "learn",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A GraphQL Server from scratch for learning purpose.",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "dotenv -- nodemon -e ts,graphql -x ts-node src/index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "graphql-yoga": "^1.18.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prisma/cli": "^2.8.1",
    "@prisma/client": "^2.8.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.2",
    "dotenv-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm also running into this, deploying on heroku.

2020-10-11T05:48:46.590156+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/node/bin/node[133]: ../src/node_http_parser_impl.h:529:static void node::{anonymous}::Parser::Initialize(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `args[3]->IsInt32()' failed.


Looks like a good thing to open on their github as an issue.

Comment: @Mark yap, I've created an issue in nodejs repository. For now you need to downgrade your node version to `v12.18.4` or upgrading it to `v14`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your issue is related to [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/35572). Currently there's an issue with Node.js version *12.19.0* that Heroku uses and there's a dependency named `undici` that's causing the issue. It should work if you try it with Node 14 in Heroku.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've created an issue in nodejs repository and the error only show in node `v12.19.0`. For now I'm downgrading my node version to `v12.18.4` and it's work properly.

Thank you for the answer.